# Как реализовать поля в django admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как реализовать поля чтобы добавлялись по нажатию на кнопку в djaango admin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Объясните корректнее.

Comment: У меня есть поле ingredeen = models.CharField('Ингредиенты', max_length=50),Мне нужно чтоб при нажатие на кнопку добавлялась еще такое же поле

Comment: наводящий вопрос - и что вы быдете с этим делать? как хранить? все ингредиенты в одной строке?

Comment: если да - это это плохой ответ. вам стоит пересмотреть сркутруру бд, вынести ингредиенты в отдельную модель, либо хранить в JsonField или других подобных полях

Comment: если да - это это плохой ответ. вам стоит пересмотреть сркутруру бд, вынести ингредиенты в отдельную модель, либо хранить в JsonField или других подобных полях. во втором случае ищите приложения/пакеты для работы с такими данными, либо пишите свое поле формы с соответсвующим JS